# Issue with the anchor in the URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, anchor, hashtag

In my URL the Anchor isn't working. I think the problem is that the first hashtag is destroying the second one. Here is a example link:

www.mywebsite.com/de/topic.html?#tab=tab1#anchor

Tab is for a tabcomponent on which I'd like to have direct links. For every Tab I have a own value (tab1 in this example). It can only get selected with the hashtag, so my Anchor isn't working. Unfortunately theres no way to edit the Tabcomponent.

Is there a chance to replace the first hashtag? Or any other solution?

Comment: Do you have any relevant code to show? Perhaps make a fiddle so we can see your problem duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) defines in 3.5  that any uniform resource identifier (URI) can have no more than one fragment identifier. All characters following the first number sign (`#`) are considered to be part of the anchor.

The fragment identifier (sometimes called "anchor" in informal speech, accesible as `location.hash` in the DOM) denotes a fragment of the document (the actual anchor: in modern websites an element with the corresponding id attribute, or historically an a element with the corresponding name attribute).

Browsers usually parse the fragment identifier and  jump to the matching fragment.

Sites that display content in tabs must parse the fragment identifier and change the visibility or display properties of the tabbed content so that the right content is visible when a user visits an URL that identifies a tab. When a user clicks on another tab, it must update the visibility and change the URL.

If you want to use complex hash navigation,  you will have to extend the existing script logic.